# SQL: Проверка на наличие записи в таблице, вывод собственных значений

Tags: sql

Итак, ситуация такая:
мне нужно проверить, есть ли нужное значение ("abcd")в таблице.

В случае того, если значения нет, нужно получить сообщение (с помощью SELECT), к примеру, такое: "value abcd is missing".

Как это возможно выполнить с помощью SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Два стопроцентно работающих варианта:

Верная реалиция предложенная коллегой с моими комментариями:

```
SELECT
      CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT TOP (1)
            1
          FROM [Table]
          WHERE [field] = 'abcd') THEN 'EXISTS'
        ELSE 'value abcd is missing'
      END
```

Второй вариант:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [Table] where [field]='abcd')>0
BEGIN
     SELECT 'EXISTS'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
     SELECT 'value abcd is missing'
END
```

IF Через `EXISTS`:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP (1) 1 FROM [Table] where field='abcd')
BEGIN
     SELECT 'EXISTS'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
     SELECT 'value abcd is missing'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот это , например, должно работать в MS SQL:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM Table where field='abcd')=1 THEN 'EXISTS' ELSE 'value abcd is missing' END
```

По идее, и во многих других СУБД это должно сработать.

Можно еще тоже самое через IF ELSE сделать.

Comment: С синтаксисом беда, надо убрать либо EXISTS, либо =1